# yum works on one vm but not from other vm on same vlan

Tags: linux, networking, yum, vmware, oracle-linux

I am having a strange problem here. 
2 OEL7 VMs are built on same vlan, with same resolve.conf, yum.conf and *.repo. Firewall/iptables are stopped on these VMs. One can access oracle repo (apparently curl yum.oracle.com works for that vm) and other cannot. The failed VM shows connection refused if I curl to yum.oracle.com. Ping is fine from both VM.

Comment: Does ping on both systems show the same ip address for yum.oracle.com?

Comment: Yes, both VMs show same ip address for ping yum.oracle.com

Comment: While comparing between VMs, I found both have same UUID in ifcfg-ens192 file. Then I commented out the UUID of failed VM but still no luck. Googled more and generate new UUID by "uuidgen ens192" , that did not help either. FYI, the VMs have been cloned from template.